# Merge Files using ksh

Tags: merge

I have 2 files in a directory (Files given below are only Examples)

### File 1

abcd
efghi

1234
5678

### File2

qwert
werty
poqrs

### Desried Output

abcd
efghi

1234
5678
qwert
werty
poqrs

Currently i used the following code to merge the records in the file

for file in *.txt
do
cat "$file"
echo
done > output.txt

This is merging the records as expected but the total size of merged file not matching with the sum of sizes of files.

For Ex: if the File1 size is 120, File 2 size is 140 the Merged File Size is coming to be 262 and not 260.

I guess it is because of the echo statement in the code.

can any one help me out if there is any way to merge the data as stated above apart from the above way.

Thanks in advance,
Anand

Answer (score -1):

This will cat the file contents directly into file "output.txt" via **append** *">>"* instead of the original code of cat to stdout, then echo with an extra null terminator.

```
for file in *.txt ; do
    cat $file >> output.txt
done
```